# alias to source a bash file from another dir and return to current dir

Tags: bash, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to `source` the [Firefox addon sdk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html). To do so, I must `cd` into the sdk's dir, then run `source bin/activate`. If I don't `cd` into that dir, and source directly from whatever path I am in currently, the following happens:

```
$ source ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk/bin/activate
Welcome to the Add-on SDK. Run 'cfx docs' for assistance.
$ cfx
-bash: cfx: command not found
```

I want to have an alias for that, which cd's into the sdk, sources it, then returns to my current directory:

`alias acfx='cd ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk && source bin/activate && cd "$(dirname "$0")"'`

This sources the sdk correctly, but alas does not return to the directory I invoked the alias:

```
$ acfx
Welcome to the Add-on SDK. Run 'cfx docs' for assistance.
dirname: illegal option -- b
usage: dirname path
```

I am lost here, how do I return to the original directory? Or specify a 'working directory' for `source`?

Comment: FYI, if you add the SDK's 'bin' directory to your $PATH, you can just run cfx that way without needing the activate / virtualenv-esque environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute cd and subsequent command in a sub-shell like this:

```
(cd ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk && source bin/activate)
```

If for some reason you don't want to create sub-shell then use `cd -` to change dir to the the previous dir:

```
cd ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk && source bin/activate && cd -
```

Comment: yeah, I tried with the sub-shell, but the sourced script needs to add variables and stuff to the shell I'll be working with; the second approach just works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pushd` and `popd` shell builtins:

```
alias acfx='pushd ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk && source bin/activate && popd'
```

The `$(dirname "$0")` trick only works when invoked from a script; on the prompt, `$0` will be `bash`, so you'd try to return to `.` (because `dirname bash` prints `.`). In your case, I'm guessing `$0` is something different; maybe `-bash`?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the previous path and then go to it:

```
prev_dir=$(pwd); ... your commands ... ; cd $prev_dir
```

In your case:

```
alias acfx='prev_dir=$(pwd); cd ~/src/devtools/addon-sdk; source bin/activate; cd $prev_dir'
```

Comment: how would I do that in an alias definition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not curious if this solves your original problem. can you try cd to that dir, source , cd to some other temp dir, and then try cfx ? i mean sourcing should not be different whether done from the current dir, or some specific dir. If the script assumes the user to be present in the current dir, then it's wrong. May be in that case adding `export PATH=~/src/devtools/addon-sdk:$PATH` in script might help

Comment: the 3rd party script needs to be sourced from a specific dir, and that's just the way it is; adding the path you mentioned didn't allow me to source bin/activate